# looking for 80s-90s sci-fi anime

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I am looking for an animated series or a movie, which I suspect is an anime, that I've seen somewhere in (probably early) 90s. I barely remember anything about it but it has been nagging me for decades.

- In one of the scenes, a group of people are observing/studying (they are observing it from a distance in a wild, like looking from binoculars or through a video feed) a 'new' unknown to them robot, think Han Solo observing probe droid in Empire strikes back. This robot can transform into several forms: one is large cat-like, as a leopard , the other is more bull-like and there are probably other forms. This happens in some remote place, probably a desert.
- Later a large group of these robots attack some village or town
- There is also a scene on some large advanced spaceship  that is either travelling towards or observing a planet where this takes place.

I am pretty sure about the first point but last two might be false memories of some other shows.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this Stack. Small additions that would help your question would be to tell us which language you saw this in, and which country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of the short lived Robotech II: The Sentinels series from 1986. Only three episodes were animated and eventually turned into a movie.

Being Robotech, there are lots of transforming mecha, though the ones that match your description don't themselves transform.

The relevant part starts with the alien Invid attacking Tirol, the mostly abandoned home world of their enemies the Robotech Masters (who are themselves heading to Earth for events shown in the second part of the original Robotech series). They deploy a variety of crab-like mecha and unmanned combat robots - most notably ones that look like cats - called Hellcats, and a couple of bipedal designs that get less air time.

There are scenes where two of the remaining Tirolians observe these combat robots through a video feed and then go out to try to capture one, and others where the few defenders try to fight back against a wave of Hellcats. The entire planet has a barren, desert aesthetic.

The sequences showing the attacks are followed by ones in space from the view of the Invid, and from a Human/Zentraedi (yet another species; the antagonists of the first part of Robotech, now allies) expedition that is preparing to head to Tirol to confront the Masters.

The whole film is on YouTube but of dubious legality so I won't link it, but a clip showing the Hellcats attacking is [here](https://youtu.be/cJt_FhM_HrE).

Comment: Also found a scene where some other Tirolians are watching oncoming bipedal robots through binoculars just before dropping a cliff on them. So *looking from binoculars or through a video feed* both match.

Comment: Well this is awkward. The Robotech II series do fit  my description, but as I watch it I cannot say : This is it.  I don't recognize it. But it was a long time ago so my description is basically all I remember and its possible that I just forgot. So I'll wait and see if someone  suggests any other show and if nothing comes up I guess I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @lolcow I don't think Sentinels got a lot of distribution outside of hardcore Robotech fans so that's not too surprising, but... it's such a great fit for your description!